# `UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME` on Bootcamp Windows 10

Tags: windows, bootcamp, startup, ssd

Hi all — a few years back, I set up a SanDisk Extreme PRO 128GB SSD flash drive to act as a bootable disk for Windows 10 when plugged into my fiancée's early 2015 MBP (currently running Catalina) so she could play the Sims on "native" hardware.

Lately we've been plagued by Windows being slow and the MBP not recognizing the SanDisk as the default boot drive when plugged in, but today it reached a new level of depravity. Here's the chain of events:

1. Fiancée booted up the MBP with SanDisk plugged in; MBP didn't boot to Windows, so she restarted, held down the Option key, and selected the SanDisk as the boot drive (listed as "EFI Volume").
2. Windows loading screen hanged, then Windows (for an unknown reason) said it needed to load into Repair Mode and automatically restarted.
3. MBP rebooted and did not recognize SanDisk as the boot drive; restarted MBP and held down the Option key to select the boot drive, but the SanDisk didn't appear; logged into MBP and SanDisk still didn't appear, but other USB devices worked.
4. Reset NVRAM/PRAM on MBP; SanDisk is recognized again.
5. Attempted to load Windows *again*; now stuck back on Step 3.

In short, macOS won't recognize the SanDisk as being plugged in, and we can't load to Windows. What can we try to resolve this?

Comment: The problems could be because you installed on a flash drive instead of a external HDD or external SSD. Another option would be to install Windows on the internal drive as a dual boot. If internal drive is to small, then upgrade to a [larger SSD](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/ssd/owc/macbook-pro-retina-display/2013-2014-2015).

Comment: Fortunately, the SanDisk everything's installed on _is_ an external SSD — the easiest first step, at least in my mind, is to get the MBP to recognize that the flash drive is plugged into a USB port. Would you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: Your SanDisk is **NOT** a SSD. You added a D to SS to get SSD! It is a *"SanDisk Extreme PRO 128GB **SS** flash drive"*. You are falsely calling it a *"SanDisk Extreme PRO 128GB **SSD** flash drive"*. Based on what you posted, [here](https://imgur.com/a/cwGUEli) is what I think you are using. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are right. Do you have any ideas to get the MBP to recognize the Solid State Flash Drive?